# Can't remove headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, koa

I am getting inconsistent results from my server. Sometimes the right response is sent and sometimes I get the error

> Can't remove headers after they are sent

Using Node.js, Koa.js, and Mongoose

```
router
.get('/events/', function* getEvent() {
  let eventList = [];
  yield Event.find({}, (error, events) => {
    if (error) {
      this.response.body = 'Unable to get events.';
      this.status = 404;
      return;
    }

    eventList = events;
    eventList.sort((first, second) => {
      // sort implementation
    });

    this.response.body = eventList;
    this.status = 200;
  });
});
```

Comment: This is normally caused by an inconsistent res.end() call. If that's not the case could you provide a bit more context or code?

Comment: Edited code block to show the whole method. I noticed that sometimes end call is not consistent. Sometimes the Event.find() gets executed sometimes it does not.

Comment: There's a chance that this is because of how you handle errors (can you add the code for that as well?). Also, it seems that your `yield` is superfluous, as you're also passing a callback to `Event.find()`.

Comment: @safaiyeh Right, but focusing on the error itself, it's saying the headers are being sent, and then something is trying to modify them afterwards. This signals, to me at least, that the call is either being made twice or you're firing this call, not ending the response, and firing another get/post which conflicts with it

Comment: Added error implementation

Comment: @safaiyeh that looks okay. You're not using additional middleware that may be causing the error?

Comment: No middleware, just KoaJS.

Comment: Well, you _are_ using the router middleware.

Comment: Your code is very wrong and involves a race condition. Remove the callback to Event.find. Instead, refactor it into `events = yield Event.find(); ...set status/body ...`. Make sure Event.find even returns a promise that can be awaited by yield.

Comment: @danneu that did the trick. Submit an answer and I will accept that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by your callback which introduces a race condition since your yield isn't waiting for it to finish. In Koa v1.x, you generally only use a callback API to return a promise.

Here's how you'd write your example with Koa v1.x:

```
router
  .get('/events', function * () {
    let events
    try {
      events = yield Event.find({})
    } catch (err) {
      this.status = 503
      this.body = 'Unable to get events'
      return
    }
    events = sort(events)
    this.body = events  // Implicit 200 response
  })
```

`Event.find` just needs to return something yieldable like a promise. Check to see if the library your using has a promise-returning version.

Though normally you'd just write it like this:

```
router
  .get('/events', function * () {
    let events = yield Event.find({})
    events = sort(events)
    this.body = events
  })
```

Since it's an internal error (500 response) if `Event.find` is down. Koa will turn uncaught errors into 500 responses.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, after you set `this.status` to 200, it throws an error because this.response.body is probably `undefined.` Go ahead and `console.log()` this.response.body and see if it is defined. If it is `undefined`, I would guess `req.body` is not being populated correctly OR it is an asynchronous node problem. Basically, eventList.sort() is asynchronously executing as this.response.body = eventList is set. Thus eventList is not sorted yet when you set it. To fix this put it inside eventList.sort() callback.

EDIT: after seeing your comment, I am pretty sure it is asynchronous problem now. Let me know if putting the last two lines inside the sort call works out for you.

Comment: Added the line stop the sort call, problem still persists.

Comment: Please let me know what is in console.log in this.response.body

Comment: It just occured to me: you might want this.request.body, not this.response.body

Comment: I added console.log(this.response.body); after the assignment. IT crashes before it logs. When it is successful, the response is defined.

Comment: this.request.body is undefined.

Comment: Added error handling. Sort does not seem to throw any errors when header error happens.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to debug this error yourself. The gist of your error is that, the response is being sent, and then it's finding an error in response.body but it cannot change it because it's already been set.