# Can't remove headers after they are sent in Koa

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa

I coded a minimalist server to manage REST services. The only coded route is supposed to retrieve data from mongo, then to send it to the client. Code is below.

```
var kr = require('koa-route');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

var events = function * ()
{
    var _this = this;

    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/eventdata", function(error, db) {
        if (error) throw(error);
        console.log("Connecté à la base de données");

        db.collection('events').find().toArray(function(err, array)
        {
            console.log('returning %d objects', array.length);
            db.close();
            _this.body = {eventsArray : array};

        });
    });
}

app.use(kr.get('/events', events));

app.listen(3000);
```

Koa is version 1.2.4

When I try to reach it, I get the error message "Can't remove headers after they are sent". I managed to understand that the program (sort of) finishes to send back response before the find() is over. So when the _this.body = { ... } is called, this causes the error.

Now question is : how to fix that ?
I just began to practice Koa, so there are a lot of stuff I'm not used to.

I tested solution proposed here : [Can't remove headers after they are sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450258/cant-remove-headers-after-they-are-sent) but it doesn't work. I get the following error message :

```
eventsArray = yield db.collection('events').find({})
                    ^^
SyntaxError : unexpected identifier
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you need to wrap db req to promise. Try in this way

```html
var kr = require('koa-route');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var eventsPromise = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/eventdata", function(error, db) {
        if (error){ 
           return reject(error);
        }
        console.log("Connecté à la base de données");

        db.collection('events').find().toArray(function(err, array)
        {
            console.log('returning %d objects', array.length);
            db.close();
            return reslove({eventsArray : array});
        });
    });
  });
}
var events = function * ()
{
    var event = yiled eventsPromise();
    this.body = event;
}

app.use(kr.get('/events', events));

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Impressive ! Could you please explain a little bit ? I guess I didn't totally understood the "yield" concept...

Comment: Glad to help.
Koa - is using a generator function as middlewares. (read some about generators here https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators)

So, yiled - like a pause of generator function. We are waiting for result of promise, and  then go to the next

Comment: Almost all simply. Thanks a lot !!